# problems with indexing, unterminated regexp meets end of file

Tags: haml

I wrote this while trying to index data

```
= form_tag blog_posts_path, method: :get do
%p
= text_field_tag :query, params[:query]
= submit_tag "Search", name: nil
```

and I get this error and I really don't know how to fix it:

```
/home/marina/project/app/views/blog_posts/index.haml:15: syntax error, unexpected ')'
));}\n<p></p>\n#{
 ^
/home/marina/project/app/views/blog_posts/index.haml:15: syntax error, unexpected '<'
));}\n<p></p>\n#{
      ^
/home/marina/project/app/views/blog_posts/index.haml:15: unterminated regexp meets end of fail
/home/marina/project/app/views/blog_posts/index.haml:15: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

Extracted source (around line #15):

```
12: %br
13: 
14: = form_tag blog_posts_path, method: :get do
15: %p
16: = text_field_tag :query, params[:query]
17: = submit_tag "Search", name: nil
18:
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that seems an indentation problem. You should indent once the %p and twice the last two lines.

Comment: ok it's fixed now i have a box to search but whenever i write  a work and hit the search button nothing changes at all, and i've already indexed the data i guess

Comment: marina@ubuntu:~$ cd project
marina@ubuntu:~/project$ rake db:setup
Generated indexes for BlogPost